# TextView variable name + string combining

Tags: java, android, variables, textview

question with either easy or impossible answer, dunno. I'm new and I want to create new TextView's within a loop, but I'm having problem with TextView's variable name. I need it to be unique.. Thanks.

```
    int i = 1;
    while (i<=10) {
        String asd = String.valueOf(i);
        TextView textView+asd = new TextView(this);
        //new textView+asd.setText("asdd");
        i++;
    }
```

Comment: That will run until you run out of memory.  You'll never break out of the loop.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2432898/1920161 - you can see if that answer helps as I believe the OP has the same question as you

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it like you posted. You need to create array of TextView's. `TextView textViews[] = new TextView[10]; for(int i=0; i<textViews.length; i++) { textViews[i] = new TextView(this); }`

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use your layout and do something like this

```
final int x = 5; // # of TextViews you want
int i = 0;

final TextView[] textViews = new TextView[x];

while (i < x) {
    TextView newTextView = new TextView(this); // this needs to be the proper context
    newTextView.setText("Whatever");
    layout.addView(newTextView); // Need to bring in your layout before this
    textViews[i] = newTextView;
    i++;
}
```

Comment: textViews[x] = newTextView; 
if x = 5; then all newTextView's won't save as textViews[5]??