# Java factory pattern creating objects

Tags: java, object, design-patterns, factory

I am designing a solution in Java, and I have to create n objects, based on property values. I am using factory design pattern.

Using the classic example of shape and shape types

```
String myShapes="circle,square,circle,rectangle"  // This is from a property file
for ( shapeType : myShapes.split("," ) {
   ShapeFactory shapeFactory = new ShapeFactory();
   Shape shape1 = shapeFactory.getShape(shapeType ); 
   shape1.doSomething(); 
}
```

Can someone tell me  whether the following is right approach in creating the objects? I don't know how many objects I will have to create during compile time.

Comment: Looks ok... Can you please clarify why do you think it is a problem?

Comment: Can u post the code for ShapeFactory ?

Comment: Its correct provided your getShape method returns a specific sub-type of Shape based on the String passed to it

Answer (score 0):

The design looks ok but it needs to include code to handle exceptional situations. I have listed few steps. You will know the limitation of your existing design as you go along with the task.

> - When you need to create excessively large number of objects, your design needs to be memory efficient.
> - Keeping track of the objects (tracking similar objects with same       properties)
> - The design needs to account for destroying the objects after their       use, since large number of objects (creating them in for loop! is
>     going to be memory intensive!).
> - Is it ok if Garbage Collector picks up the object and destroys anytime during the execution? Implementing a finalize block is needed
>     when dealing with large number of objects.

Here are few links on few related topics.

[add objects with different name through for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432866/add-objects-with-different-name-through-for-loop)

http://www.java-forums.org/new-java/25967-loop-create-objects.html

http://www.java-forums.org/new-java/56024-create-new-objects-loop.html

https://www.java.net/node/675897